# Bluemix: Is it possible to change app runtime settings (JVM, environment variables)?

Tags: ibm-cloud

does Bluemix allow to change app runtime settings (JVM, environment variables)?

-thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Java applications are run in a Java runtime environment (JRE) that is provided and configured by the Liberty buildpack. The Liberty buildpack also makes it possible to configure the JRE version or type, customize the JVM options, or overlay the JRE functions. Please take a look at [Customizing the JRE](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/liberty/customizingJRE.html) for more information.

Generally speaking, you can add environment variables to a runtime both using the Bluemix Dashboard and the cf CLI (*cf set-env* command) and you can access them from your applications. I suggest you to also take a look at the docs for each specific runtime in order to know what are the possible customizations for each one of them.